# Django REST: Why use LOGIN when you can AUTHENTICATE?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm wondering, why use Login when you have an Authentication Token?

I mean I'm using Postman to test my `urls`, `serializers` and `views`.
I can log in and I have to use a different `urls` to get my `access token` and my `refresh token`.

`Login`: `POST`http://localhost:8000/login/

```json
{
    "username":"Max",
    "password":"Yolo1234"
}
-----
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "Max",
    "is_a": true,
    "is_e": false
}
```

`Token`: `POST`http://localhost:8000/api/token/

```json
{
    "username":"Max",
    "password":"Yolo1234"
}
-----
{
    "refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTU4Nzc1OTQ5NCwianRpIjoiOWUzNjg1OTZhZWViNDRiNWE2Nzg3Y2E0ZDhkODQ5OWQiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyfQ.W9a2fCxUF9Hrf51l-Ecx7nt2tmt2QvLhr4pp2DBUuvE",
    "access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTg3NjgwMjk0LCJqdGkiOiIwNDI3MmJhMjljNmM0ODk3ODg4YTI5YTBkZjViZDljZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjJ9.0sid4rSbDUX3LHX7X74Cw1H9_lSlwD5ppfC3ctLGFSo"
}
```

And when I'm trying to `POST` an article, I need to authenticate with my `access token`.
But when I log out, I can still `POST` an article by using my `access token` without being logged in.

So I have some difficulty understanding the need to have the two in the project.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: For the API one does not login/logout, this is normally for browsers.

Comment: Oooh, so with the API there is technically no login/logout, but when I'll be using it in my browser it will automatically ask me to log in for the same action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens are usually the preferred way for API to authenticate since it is described in RFC such as [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2).

However browsers are not able to deal with tokens - they are not very... convenient to humans.

Instead, sites have been using cookies to store session identifiers and websites can flag a session as being authenticated or not. The authentication is possible through login/logout pages where the website can ensure the username / password matches and then flag the session with that information. Hopefully, it'll not be stored client side for obvious security reasons. DRF uses `SessionAuthentication` for that.

It is quite handy when the user logs in on a website and can use that session on the API without requiring extra action from the user.

Note that you may use session authentication with other things than browsers but that's usually not what is done.

Comment: SO does it mean that you either work with SessionAuthentication if you only expect users to log in and access your website with less restrictions than a visitor. Instead of generating JWT which would be more useful if I intended to open my API to be used by other websites. Correct? Also the session ID and CSRF would be safe in a cookie.

Comment: You can work with both Sessionauthentication and token authentication. DRF can deal with multiple authentication methods. CSRF are only enforced for requests using session  authentication - doesn't make sense with tokens.